# How to create drop shadow for Rectangle on QtQuick 2.0

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

How can i draw a drop shadow for a `Rectangle` visual item on QtQuick 2.0?
I like to draw a drop shadow for my main window (I have a transparent and no-decorated window)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a workaround for the clipped shadow issue, you can put your `Rectangle` in an `Item`, with additionnal margin to take blur radius in account, and apply shadow on that container:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    width: 320
    height: 240

    Item {
        id: container
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width:  rect.width  + (2 * rectShadow.radius)
        height: rect.height + (2 * rectShadow.radius)
        visible: false

        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            width: 100
            height: 50
            color: "orange"
            radius: 7
            antialiasing: true
            border {
                width: 2
                color: "red"
            }
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

    DropShadow {
        id: rectShadow
        anchors.fill: source
        cached: true
        horizontalOffset: 3
        verticalOffset: 3
        radius: 8.0
        samples: 16
        color: "#80000000"
        smooth: true
        source: container
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot it, but you should specify `visible: false` on the Item container, because the DropShadow effect duplicates the source item on its own, so it will avoid strange rendering issues.

Comment: In my case Qt 5.15.2 this caused the internals of container not receive any touch/mouse events on iOS.

Answer (score 9):

Just use [`DropShadow`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgraphicaleffects/qml-qtgraphicaleffects1-dropshadow.html) from the [`QtGraphicalEffects`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgraphicaleffects/qmlmodule-qtgraphicaleffects1-qtgraphicaleffects-1-0.html) module.

A complete, working example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "blue"

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "red"
    }

    DropShadow {
        anchors.fill: rect
        cached: true
        horizontalOffset: 3
        verticalOffset: 3
        radius: 8.0
        samples: 16
        color: "#80000000"
        source: rect
    }
}
```

Note that you will see a number of warnings like this:

> file:///opt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/DropShadow.qml:391:5:
>   QML SourceProxy: Binding loop detected for property "output"
>   file:///opt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/private/GaussianDirectionalBlur.qml:66:5:
>   QML SourceProxy: Binding loop detected for property "output"
>   file:///opt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/private/GaussianDirectionalBlur.qml:61:5:
>   QML SourceProxy: Binding loop detected for property "output"
>   file:///opt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/private/GaussianDirectionalBlur.qml:66:5:
>   QML SourceProxy: Binding loop detected for property "output"
>   file:///opt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/private/GaussianDirectionalBlur.qml:61:5:
>   QML SourceProxy: Binding loop detected for property "output"
>   file:///opt/Qt5.0.1/5.0.1/gcc_64/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/private/GaussianGlow.qml:53:5: QML SourceProxy: Binding loop detected for property "output"

Those warnings are [QTBUG-28521](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28521), which has been fixed in Qt 5.0.2 (which at the time of this writing has not yet been released). Fortunately, there's no actual problem, aside from the annoying console output.

Comment: Nope! result shadow is very solid/flat. I like to have an smooth shadow.

Comment: I'll bet the reason it doesn't smoothly fade out is because of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14576547/331041

Comment: I agree... I guess that this is my problem

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question... I've been searching for a better way to do this. This is my quick and dirty way of accomplishing a drop shadow effect for a QML Rectangle for the time being.

```
Rectangle{
    width: 500
    height: 500
    color: "dark grey"


    Rectangle {
        id: backgroundRect
        width: 200
        height: 150
        radius: 5
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "red"

        Rectangle {
            id: dropShadowRect
            property real offset: Math.min(parent.width*0.025, parent.height*0.025)
            color: "purple"
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            z: -1
            opacity: 0.75
            radius: backgroundRect.radius + 2
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.leftMargin: -offset
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: offset
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the result shadow is very flat. I like to have an smooth shadow

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi yea, I definetly agree. The only way to make it look smoother would be to fool around with gradients... I wish there was a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code above and it in fact adds a shadow, although in my case simply adding another rectangle with a bit on an offset gave me an effect that I liked more.

```
Rectangle{

    id: rec_Shadow
    height:rect_withShadow.height
    width: rect_withShadow.width
    border.color: "#B3B3B3"
    color: "#C5C5C5"

    anchors{
            verticalCenter: rect_withShadow.verticalCenter
            horizontalCenter:  rect_withShadow.horizontalCenter
            horizontalCenterOffset: 5
            verticalCenterOffset: 5
        }
    radius: rect_withShadow.radius
}
```

Next you add the Rectangle on which you want the shadow, and you call it rect_withShadow